# PCA and Discriminant Analysis Under Multicollinearity

Tags: pca, multicollinearity

I'm trying to run discriminant function analysis on 27 acoustic, temporal and descriptive variables I obtained from animal calls. However, a number of these variables are collinear because they were calculated from other variables. For example: f0 range = f0 high - f0 low.

Previous work using the same variables utilized 2 PCAs to create component scores (PCA 1: Frequency; PCA 2: Component Scores 1, Temporal and Descriptive, on which the discriminant analyses were run (individuality, context etc.)

However, I think this was not the correct option because 1) the PCA correlation matrix is "not definite positive" and 2) the components aren't going to be correct anyway because the PCAs aren't detecting these collinear relationships.

Accordingly, I was wondering if there is a method that allows me to reclassify the variables into scores before DA that takes collinearity into account? Or, is my best option to remove the derived variables or their constituent elements before running the analysis (Using the example above, to remove f0 range OR remove f0 high AND f0 low)?

Comment: Your last example illustrates a simple principle. You can reconstruct range from high and low, but not vice versa. Therefore drop range. In general, exact linear dependencies just mess up methods here.

Comment: Terminology suggestion: when using PCA, always refer to principal components (PCs), and never factors.